# Strange margin in wordpress site

Tags: css, wordpress, background

Hello i'm making site in wordpress and I have strange error. On page at the top i have white space [enter link description here](http://yakuzaki.webd.pl)
How I can fix it.

Answer (score 1):

It's because of the `" "` right under your `<body>` tag

Remove it and it should works.

Btw, you should place `<meta>` and `<title>` in the `<head>`, not `<body>` as well as the `<script>` tag at the bottom of the page right before closing `</body>`

Comment: But in files I dont have this.

Comment: It's strange because in files i have meta, and title in head section

Comment: @user3211948 I'm not sure why also since I don't know anything beside viewing your page source :(

Answer (score 0):

see if you have any extra spaces there. Remove all white spaces and line breaks. That would help